# lightning-formatted-date-time displays incorrect translation for Spanish

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am wondering is this is a bug ?

**User record has following setting**

[image]

**End result for Spanish if the Date is April 2023**

[image]

**End result for Spanish if the Date is May 2023**

[image]

**See Code Snippet**
HTML:

```
<div role="group" class="slds-col slds-size_10-of-12">
    <h4 class="slds-show_inline-block"  tabindex="0">{deadlineTitle} {langData._1}</h4>
    <p class="slds-show_inline-block slds-float_right"  tabindex="0">{daysLeft} {langData._2}</p>
    <p class="due-date slds-var-m-top_small" tabindex="0"><lightning-formatted-date-time time-zone="UTC" value={deadlineDate} year="numeric" month="long" day="numeric"></lightning-formatted-date-time></p>
    <p class="slds-var-m-top_small" tabindex="0">{langData._3}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
this.deadlineDate = data.deadlineDate;
```

Apex class:

```
// Code Snippet
QuarterDeadlineWrapper quarterwrapper = new QuarterDeadlineWrapper();
Q1__c q1ToUse = QuarterServices.determineQuarter1ToUseForDeadline(today);
quarterwrapper.deadlineDate = q1ToUse.Due_Date__c;
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code snippet that can be used to replicate this behaviour in my org?

Comment: @Swetha icluded code snippet

Comment: What is the format of the date fetched in "deadlineDate" from the apex class?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this behavior in my org and it does not appear to be an issue with the translation.

When the locale is set to Spanish, the output values are shown as below for this codesnippet

```
<div class="slds-box">
<h2 class="header">Date and Time Formatting</h2>
<p><lightning-formatted-date-time time-zone="UTC" value={datetime1} year="numeric" month="long" day="numeric" ></lightning-formatted-date-time></p>
<p><lightning-formatted-date-time time-zone="UTC" value={datetime2} ></lightning-formatted-date-time></p>
<p><lightning-formatted-date-time time-zone="UTC" value={datetime1} ></lightning-formatted-date-time></p>     
</div>


Output:
Date and Time Formatting
29 de mayo de 2022
abr 25, 2022 
may 29, 2022
```

I see that `Mayo` is shown as `May` just like how `Abril` is shown as `Abr` and it is not an issue with the translation